# Pinch Zoom OpenGL Orthographic Projection Matrix

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I'm having some trouble trying to implement pinch to zoom an image displayed with an OpenGLES orthographic projection under iOS. I'm trying to scale and translate the projection matrix so that the zoom stays centered under the pinch location.

Under my update: method I configure the matrix:

```
float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f / aspect, 0.5f / aspect, -1.0f, 1.0f);
projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, GLKMatrix4MakeScale(newScale, newScale, 1.0f)); // scale
projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation((endPan1.x + endPan2.x), 0.0 - (endPan1.y + endPan2.y), 0.0f)); //pan
```

Using a pinch gesture recognizer I'm fetching the values for newScale and endPan1. (endPan2 comes from a two-fingered pan recognizer.):

```
- (void)pinchDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender;
{
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    lastScale = newScale;        
    startPan1.x = endPan1.x;
    startPan1.y = endPan1.y;    

    GLKMatrix4 pinchMatrix = projectionMatrix;
    CGFloat aspectInv = self.view.bounds.size.height / self.view.bounds.size.width;
    // Get the center offset of the projection matrix:
    GLKVector2 middleVect = GLKVector2Make(pinchMatrix.m30, pinchMatrix.m31);
    CGPoint pointPinch = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    GLKVector2 touchVectPinch = GLKVector2Make((2 * pointPinch.x / self.view.bounds.size.width - 1),
                                               (2 * (self.view.bounds.size.height-pointPinch.y) / self.view.bounds.size.height - 1));
    touchToMiddle = GLKVector2Make((middleVect.x - touchVectPinch.x) * (1.0 / pinchMatrix.m00), (middleVect.y - touchVectPinch.y) * ((1.0 / pinchMatrix.m00) * aspectInv)  );    
}

newScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale] - (1.0 - lastScale);

if (newScale < 0.25) {
    newScale = 0.25;
}
if (newScale > 4.0) {
    newScale = 4.0;
}

// Pan the image to center the scale under the touch point:???
endPan1.x = (((newScale - 1.0) * 0.5) * (touchToMiddle.x )) - startPan1.x ;
endPan1.y = 0.0 - ((((newScale - 1.0) * 0.5) * (touchToMiddle.y )) + startPan1.y); 
}
```

The result is that the image does not quite stay centered under the pinch location whilst zooming. It kinda half works... which makes me think I must be close???

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?

Comment: I'm still struggling with this one... I have some partially working code at the moment but in needs more work... I suspect a better answer might be to use a UIScrollView as describes in the 2012 WWDC video 'Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views'.

Comment: how do you plan to use scroll views to help with OpenGL? i don't think thats the answer to this issue

Comment: Watch the video! You pass the scale and offset parameters from the UIScrollView to your matrix without actually embedding your content in it. The nice part about that is your get some of the nice rubber-band style behaviour for free.

Comment: I had tried to use `UISCrollView` for my program and have decided against it because it moves your whole view and it does that around upper left screen point. To modify it you would need to write code manually for which i didnt had nerves because i had "half-working" solution. That solution now works, but i have switched from Quartz2D to OpenGL and it does't work as it should. Now i  have some strange shootings off on z axis. By reading more stuff it seems we need to transform screen coords to opengl units. I am still searching.

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure how your image is placed on screen, but you should probably be translating your image relative to the middle point of your screen. so if your average pinch point is the top right of your screen, then you should translate by the amount your pinch is away from the middle in the x and y direction. This translation may need to be scaled depending on how 'far away' your image is from the camera (even though its orthographic). you will most likely need to play around with those numbers to find what works for you.

A possible alternative way is to not use an orthographic view, use a perspective, then you can adjust the field of view for the zoom effect and just move the camera over the point where it should be zooming in to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.The image is drawn as a textured grid, spanning -0.5, -0.5 to +0.5, +0.5 on the x,y axis

Comment: Surely the translation of the image would be relative to the scale factor and position of the pinch relative to the center of the image, rather than center of the screen? My thinking was the translation would be equal to: half the scale factor multiplied by the distance from the pinch to the image center? So if one pinched the top right of the image (0.5, 0.5), and scaled it to 2.0, then the translation would be half the scale factor, multiplied by 2*(the pinch coordinates relative to the image center)?

Comment: ah yes my mistake, meant the image center not the screen center. to me what you're doing sounds right, could be a slight mistake somewhere in your code but i cant see anything wrong. i would suggest the perspective view if you haven't managed to get it to work yet. you wouldn't need to scale any translations with the perspective view and the zoom effect is really easy to achieve by adjusting the field of view.